# how to reset the color in opengl after using glColor4f

Tags: opengl

Anything rendered after you set a color uses the same color and that this spans over frames and will not be reset in-between.

Can someone suggest a way to turn off setting the color after using it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OpenGL is a state machine. Once you set the color you cannot take it back. One mechanism that you can use is the `glPushAttrib` and `glPopAttrib`. `glPushAttrib(GL_CURRENT_BIT)` saves the color and a few other things and `glPopAttrib()` restores it.

You may need to use another mechanism for what you want to do. Saving and restoring the state all the time is an expensive solution.

Comment: Can you suggest some alternatives. It will be good for me to have a look at some examples available over internet. Can you direct me to any links. thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no need to restore the color. When you want to change it you just call glColor*. If you need to keep it you can do by having a float array in the client (eg your RAM memory). 

    GLfloat master_color[4];
    master_color[0] = x;
    master_color[1] = y;
    master_color[2] = z;
    master_color[3] = w;

    glColor*(...);
    /* Draw */
    glColor4fv(master_color); /* Restore */

Answer (score 3):

If by "turn off" you mean "back to white again" you just can set the state back to glColor3f(1, 1, 1). There are a number of calls in opengl that can do this so modify this as needed.